# How to check key and values inside in object using typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, typescript-3.6

I tried to get the value in the object using typescript using **?** operator. But it's throwing an error.

```
const data = {sample:{sample1:''hai'}}
```

**!**  operator used its working fine

**Success Case**

```
if(data.sample!['sample1']){
    console.log('hai')
}
```

**?.** Operator used its throwing error

**Error Case**

```
if(data.sample?.['sample1']){
    console.log('hai')
}
```

How to get the value using **?.** operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `?.` operator (aka optional chaining operator, aka optional property access operator, aka Elvis operator) was only introduced in [TypeScript 3.7](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining).

In TypeScript 3.7+, the following code compiles and executes without a problem:

```
const data = { sample: { sample1: 'hai' } };
console.log(data.sample?.['sample1']);
```

Since you tagged your question with [typescript-3.6](/questions/tagged/typescript-3.6), you'll either have to upgrade your version of TypeScript, or revert to more explicit checking for values that are `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: I updated typescript latest version 3.7.5 but still I facing that issue.

Comment: I just tried the exact same code from my answer on the [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) which also runs 3.7.5. No problem whatsoever.